# SharePoint Workflows 2010 & 2013 in SharePoint 2019 on-premise after year of 2026

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, microsoft

Microsoft says SharePoint **2010/2013 workflows will no longer supported** in **SharePoint 2019** On-Premise after 2026. To be clear, whether the 2010 and 2013 workflows will never be stopped working in SharePoint on-premise environment or  What can be happened?

Comment: Where did you find the 2026 date for SharePoint 2013 workflows?

Comment: Why do you still have SharePoint 2010/2013 workflows in 2022, let alone expect to have them after 2026? You need to migrate to another method like Power Automate (or some better solution that supports basic business use cases like flows lasting longer than 28 days, or retention of flow runs for more than 30 days).

Comment: @ZeroRequiem We are currently on SharePoint 2013 and Migrating to 2019 SharePoint server. We have 60+ apps with around 130 SPD workflows. What is our concern is licenses 
 cost of other alternatives. So we decided to leverage 2013 workflows (ForNon complicated apps). what is your opinion here?

Comment: My opinion is that you migrate away from SharePoint workflows since they have had EoL announced for several years already. Depending on the complexity of the processes, many or all might work well in Power Automate instead.

Comment: @ZeroRequiem You are correct, when its going to cloud, we have an obligation by ISEC team as per the company data privacy policy.

Answer (score 2):

The "no longer supported" notion from Microsoft means that Microsoft won't support the product after the end date. That means that you can't ask Microsoft for support, but it doesn't mean that the workflows in this case will stop working. They will continue to live on.

In 2026 you'd probably want to migrate to a newer on-premises version of SharePoint Server, and at that time it might not be possible to use Workflows from 2010 or 2013.

> **SharePoint Server support for SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013**
> workflows SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013 based workflows will
> continue to be supported with no modification in our previous support
> posture and continue to be supported for on-premises SharePoint 2016
> and SharePoint 2019 platforms until 2026.

Ref: [SharePoint 2010 workflow retirement](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/sharepoint-2010-workflow-retirement-1ca3fff8-9985-410a-85aa-8120f626965f)

Comment: We are currently on SharePoint 2013 and Migrating to 2019 SharePoint server. We have 60+ apps with around 130 SPD workflows. What is our concern is licenses cost of other alternatives. So we decided to leverage 2013 workflows (For Non complicated apps). what is your opinion here?

Comment: @mzonerz If you have a Microsoft 365 tenant you could use Power Automate which is a powerful tool in most cases. If that's not an option I'd say you create a replica of your current Workflow Farm to a new instance and test how that works with SharePoint Server 2019. It should work, but I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: I will give a try, appreciate your response. Thank you.